# Can an Android device be used for 2FA for an Apple/iCloud account?

Tags: 2fa

Can an Android device be used for 2FA for an Apple/iCloud account? Google didn't return anything useful.

(Couldn't find any appropriate tags to use)

Comment: Please define the concrete 2FA type. Any (smart)phone can be used for 2FA where the user gets an SMS with the second factor. As far as I remember [Apple primarily uses this scheme](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915). If it supports a different 2FA system I don't know.

Comment: AFAIK on how Apple controls its environment strictly, I don't think it's possible to use non-Apple devices for [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) (see "Trusted devices" section). The alternative is to use [two-step verification](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204152) with SMS instead.